# I don't quite understand the definition of wreath product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, semidirect-product, wreath-product

In Rotman's group theory book, a wreath product is defined as

$$D\wr_\Omega Q := K \rtimes Q$$

where $\rtimes$ is the semidirect product, $K = \prod_{\omega \in \Omega} D_\omega$, and $D_\omega \cong D$ for every $\omega$ in the finite set $\Omega$. $Q$ and $D$ are said to be just 'groups'.

The problem I'm having with this definition is that, according to the definition of semidirect product, a group $G$ is the semidirect product of two subgroups $K$ and $Q$ iff:

1. $KQ = G$
2. $K \lhd G$
3. $K \cap Q = 1$.

I am not at all sure the wreath product fulfills these conditions, and I don't quite know how to check it. They all seem to imply that both $K$ and $Q$ are subgroups of $D\wr_\Omega Q$, but this group hasn't been defined in any other way than the semidirect product itself, so I'm stuck in a circular problem... What am I missing here?

Comment: See http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/External_semidirect_product

Comment: @Nex So you're saying that, as a set, $D\wr_\Omega Q$ is taken by definition to be the cartesian product of $K$ and $Q$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: The wreath product depends on a choice of homomorphism from $Q$ to some symmetric group.  Do you happen to have one of those lying around?  Maybe one whose codomain is the group of permutations of $\Omega$?

Comment: Perhaps one has to see this in a constructive way. If one takes two groups $D$ and $Q$ and follows the usual procedure for the definition of the wreath product then one gets a new group $G$ denoted by $G=D\wr Q$. One can then show that $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ etc.